# How to make a request Simplified HTTP client from node.js?

Tags: node.js

My application is running on localhost:8080 and node express is running on localhost:8081.

My task is that when specific url is hit say

```
localhost:8080/autoSearch
```

this should get read by node express middleware and make one more request hit on localhost:8080/logusercheck if that returns true make another call to get the result.

" localhost:8080/logusercheck returns true if user is logged in "

To achieve the same

Install xamp on the server and added entry as

```
ProxyPass "/autoSearch" "http://localhost:8081/autolink" ttl=120 ProxyPassReverse /autoSearch http://localhost:8081/autolink
```

In Node entry point

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 8081;

var request = require('request');
app.get('/autolink', function (req, res) {

  /*Whether user is logged in or not logged --> localhost:8080*/
  request('/logusercheck',function(error, response, body){
    console.log(response);
    console.log(error);
    console.log(body);
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.send('Searching');
        }else{
            res.send('you are not logged in');
        }
  });


});




app.listen(port,function(err,res){
    if(err){
        console.log('server error');
    }else{
        console.log('Express Started');
    }
});

console.log('server started');
```

This is always returning "you are not logged in"

Consoling

```
reponse undefined
error [Error: Invalid URI "/logusercheck"]
body undefined
```

What wrong i am doing up over here.

Answer (score 1):

`request` should be passed the full URL:

```
request('http://localhost:8080/logusercheck', ...);
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it configurable?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on how exactly you want to be able to configure it (environent variable, command line argument, rc file, ...).

Comment: can you provide me some reference to pick the best among those

Comment: There isn't "a best one", in depends entirely on how your app and deployment environment are set up. The words themselves should be enough for you to search around here or on Google to see how they work.